# Como posicionar o título no ggplot2 com o tema theme_ipsum?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho os seguintes dados

```
dados
          B  Freq
1  Feminino 61.54
2 Masculino 38.46
```

Com o código abaixo gero um gráfico de pizza utilizando o pacote `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

dados <- data.frame(B = c("Feminino", "Masculino"), 
                    Freq = c(61.54, 38.46))


(graf_B <- ggplot(dados, aes(x ="", y=Freq, fill=B)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction =1) + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_blank(), 
    plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")) + 
geom_text(data = dados,
        aes(x ="", y=Freq, label = rotulo),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
labs(title = "Gênero",
  subtitle = "",
  x="",
  y="",
  fill="")+
theme_ipsum(plot_title_size = 12,
            axis_title_size = 10))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu gostei muito desse tema, mas gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de centralizar o título. Eu já tentei e não consegui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione a linha `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` ao final do teu código:

```
(graf_B <- ggplot(dados, aes(x ="", y=Freq, fill=B)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
    coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction =1) + 
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      legend.title = element_blank(), 
      plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")) + 
    geom_text(data = dados,
              aes(x ="", y=Freq, label = rotulo),
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    labs(title = "Gênero",
         subtitle = "",
         x="",
         y="",
         fill="")+
    theme_ipsum(plot_title_size = 12,
                axis_title_size = 10) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O argumento `plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` informa que o alinhamento horizontal (`hjust`) do título deve estar na metade da tela (`0.5`). Note que se eu alterar este valor para 0 ou 1, o alinhamento ficará à esquerda ou à direita, respectivamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`hjust` pode receber qualquer valor entre 0 e 1, dependendo do tipo de alinhamento que se quiser dar para o título do gráfico.

Comment: Obrigado Marcus. Show de bola.

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu vou sugerir que você não utilize o gráfico de pizza em geral. Eu sei que a sua pergunta é especificamente sobre gráficos de pizza mas é importante salientar como há opções muito melhores.

**Qual é o problema com os gráficos de pizza?**

Como uma imagem vale mais do que mil palavras:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui você pode observar que olhando para os gráficos de pizza é difícil discernir qual categoria é maior ao passo que nos gráficos de barra equivalentes é obvio ver as diferenças. Isso de dá porque o ser humano tem uma facilidade maior em [comparar os comprimentos do que comparar ângulos](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/565d/843c2c0e60915709268ac4224894469d82d5.pdf).

**Solução Alternativa**

Nesse caso a minha solução alternativa seria como a seguir:

```
graf_B <- ggplot(dados, aes(x =B, y=Freq, fill=B)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      legend.title = element_blank(), 
      plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")) +
    geom_text(aes(y = Freq-2, label = Freq)) +
    labs(title = "Gênero",
         subtitle = "",
         x="",
         y="",
         fill="") +
    theme_ipsum(plot_title_size = 12,
                axis_title_size = 10) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

o que resulta em

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e você ainda poderia adicionar um intervalo de confiança no topo dos gráficos de barra. Não coloquei porque eu não tenho as estimativas, mas é algo que poderia ser feito já que se a porcentagem é a estimativa de algo e se estamos comparando dois grupos o ideal é sempre fornecer alguma medida de incerteza da nossa estimativa.

Comment: Concordo com você. Eu fiz o gráfico de barras em outras perguntas quando tem uma variável com mais de 3 categorias, pois representando no gráfico de pizza fica meio poluído a imagem mesmo. Valeu.

Comment: @FidelHenriqueFernandes você escolheu qual das duas respostas? Apareceu para mim por um instante que você tinha trocado a resposta selecionada.

Comment: Pensei que pudesse escolher as duas respostas. Gostei das duas. Enfim.

Comment: @FidelHenriqueFernandes caso alguma resposta lhe agrade mas você já escolheu a sua resposta preferida uma forma de você dizer que gostou é votando na reposta, o triângulo para cima. Caso você ache que a resposta é ruim você pode dar um downvote, triângulo para baixo ;-)